# F# syntax for implementing a 'virtual' property implementing an interface

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I need to implement the [IDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa97e8s4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) interface in a base class.  The interface requires a property and an indexer.  I want to provide a default implementation for both and allow subclasses to override it.  I can't seem to wield the syntax for a 'virtual' implementation with the syntax for interface implementation!  For example:

```
type ViewModelBase() =
  interface IDataErrorInfo with
    abstract Error : string with get
    default this.Error with get() = ""
```

Gives the following compile errors

> Error 1   Unexpected keyword 'abstract' in member definition. Expected
> 'member', 'override' or other
> token.    D:\MinorApps\VetCompass\VetCompass\ViewModel\ViewModelBase.fs   18  7   VetCompass
>
> Error 2   Incomplete structured construct at or before this point in
> pattern   D:\MinorApps\VetCompass\VetCompass\ViewModel\ViewModelBase.fs   19  7   VetCompass

I'm not even sure where to begin with the indexer!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All interface implementations are explicit, which means that the methods of the interface will be private when viewed as members of the class.  Thus, you can't use the `abstract` and `default` modifiers in the implementation.  Instead, you'll need to add a bit of duplication:

```
type ViewModelBase() =
    // declare a new virtual property
    abstract Error : string
    default this.Error = ""

    interface IDataErrorInfo with
       // pass through to the virtual property implementation
       member this.Error = this.Error
```

Answer (score 5):

[Object expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233237.aspx) can often be used in lieu of abstract classes and virtual methods. You can control behavior through arguments supplied to a "factory" function. Something like this:

```ml
type IMyInterface =
  abstract SayHello : unit -> string
  abstract Item : string -> obj with get

let makeMyInterface sayHello (lookup: IDictionary<string, obj>) =
  { new IMyInterface with
      member x.SayHello() = sayHello()
      member x.Item 
        with get name = lookup.[name] }
```

This probably won't work in your case, since you're constrained by the conventions of an existing framework. But it can be a nice alternative in some situations.

Comment: I love object expressions.  They make game scripting so much easier.

Comment: They also obviate the duplication and casting required by explicit interface implementations.

Comment: I don't think this works for my situation.  My framework (WPF) requires classes which implement the interface. I don't think I can pass another class implementing IDataErrorInfo instead of my view model.  If object expressions could be used to solve my issue, wouldn't this effectively be mixins / multiple inheritance and I didn't think F# lets you do that?  Object expressions would actually help me somewhere else though, thanks for posting.

Answer (score 0):

To implement IDataErrorInfo and INotifyPropertyChanged with a virtual implementation here is the code:

```
type ViewModelBase() =
    let propertyChangedEvent = new DelegateEvent<PropertyChangedEventHandler>()

    abstract Error : string with get
    default this.Error with get() = ""

    abstract Item : string -> string with get
    default this.Item with get(name) = ""

    interface INotifyPropertyChanged with
        [<CLIEvent>]
        member x.PropertyChanged = propertyChangedEvent.Publish
    member x.OnPropertyChanged propertyName = 
        propertyChangedEvent.Trigger([| x; new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName) |])

    interface IDataErrorInfo with
       // pass through to the virtual property implementation
       member this.Error = this.Error
       member this.Item with get(x) = this.Item(x)
```